# Directory which the user can't access?

Tags: java, android, directory, access-control

Is there any directory on an Android device which the user will never reach? 
I want to download a text file from my server, but the users shouldn't have access to it, because there are solutions, etc. for some levels of my game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Context.openFileOutput and Context.getFilesDir to write files to your applications data directory (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) on normal phones these can't be accessed by the user if they are set to MODE_PRIVATE. However on rooted phones the user is still able to access these files.

Answer (score 0):

The post by Neitio1 is correct. However, he linked to the Reference which might be confusing for you to use. Android provides a pretty detailed guide [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html) for saving files to the internal storage (which is inaccessible to users and other apps).